# In Aurelia templating ... What objects are iterable/repeatable?

Tags: typescript, collections, aurelia

The Aurelia documentation, states that we can use repeaters with arrays and **other iterable data types, including objects**, plus new ES6 standards such as Map and Set. Map being the recommended way to go as in the repeat.for example below:

```
<template>
      <p repeat.for="[greeting, friend] of friends">${greeting}, ${friend.name}!</p>
</template>
```

But, specifically, what types of objects (data structures, collections, etc.) are iterable/repeatable? ... and what makes them so?

Iterating over collections defined in the typescript-collections package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-collections) doesn't seem to work. It throws an error complaining that the "Value for 'collection' is non-repeatable."

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate pretty much any object/array/set/map with aurelia.

array:

```
<template>
    <p repeat.for="friend of friends">Hello, ${friend}!</p>
</template>
```

range:

```
<template>
    <p repeat.for="i of 10">${10-i}</p>
    <p>Blast off!</p>
</template>
```

sets:

```
<template>
    <p repeat.for="friend of friends">Hello, ${friend}!</p>
</template>

export class RepeaterTemplate {
    constructor() {
        this.friends = new Set();
        this.friends.add('Alice');
        this.friends.add('Bob');
        this.friends.add('Carol');
        this.friends.add('Dana');
     }
}
```

map:

```
<template>
  <p repeat.for="[greeting, friend] of friends">${greeting}, ${friend.name}!</p>
</template>

export class RepeaterTemplate {
  constructor() {
    this.friends = new Map();
    this.friends.set('Hello',
      { name : 'Alice' });
    this.friends.set('Hola',
      { name : 'Bob' });
    this.friends.set('Ni Hao',
      { name : 'Carol' });
    this.friends.set('Molo',
      { name : 'Dana' });
  }
}
```

object:

```
<template>
  <p repeat.for="greeting of friends | keys">${greeting}, ${friends[greeting].name}!</p>
</template>

export class RepeaterTemplate {
    constructor() {
      this.friends = {
        'Hello': { name : 'Alice' },
        'Hola':  { name : 'Bob' },
        'Ni Hao': { name : 'Carol' },
        'Molo': { name : 'Dana' }
       }
   }
}
export class KeysValueConverter {
  toView(obj) {
    return Reflect.ownKeys(obj);
  }
}
```

please reference: [Aurelia Repeaters](http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics#repeaters)

Comment: this excerpt from the documentation partially answers the question, which I realized it may need to be edited to avoid confusion. I am interested in objects (besides the ones mentioned in the official Aurelia documentation or in the question text) that can be iterated by the Aurelia templating engine, and more importantly, what is it that makes them iterable. I am assuming it is because they implement Symbol.iterator, not sure.

Comment: It must implement iterator. Which is why if you look at the last "object" example we pass the object to a "ValueConverter", before being displayed, in order to transform it into an iteratable type. Any non-standard iterable type would have to be done this way.